# Are FPGA and PC communications possible without a microprocessor i.e. do all FPGA dev boards have processors in?

Tags: fpga, communication, processor

I am new to FPGA design. I have worked on a Zedboard, used AXI bus and developed IP. However, I am not clear on some of the basic things. I would like to learn the following questions. My sincerest apology if they sound silly or noob.

1. Is it possible for an FPGA and a PC to communicate without a microprocessor? If so, why? If not, why not?
2. For communication, like sending data from a PC to an FPGA, do we need only USB or a microprocessor too?
3. Do all FPGA dev boards have microprocessors?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: FPGAs frequently have processors in them, but you would likely not need it to send data to/from the device over USB or PCIe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So, inside FPGA there is a processor? or is it the FPGA dev boards that have processors in them?

Comment: depends on the definition of `processor`

Comment: Take a look at the datasheet for your dev board, it will explain all of this.

Comment: It is possible. You don't need a separate processor. Either the processor can be implemented in the FPGA or there is no processor at all.

Comment: In this context, the word "processor" can be misleading.  If you mean "microprocessor" or otherwise a stored-program, general-purpose processor, then please _edit your question_ to spell that out.  An FPGA is often used as a fixed-program special purpose device to process data, and as such is a "processor" -- but that's probably not what you mean.

Comment: In my question, I meant "microprocessor" as the definition of "processor". Sorry for this generalization and for creating confusion about the terminology. I am editing it in the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, in other words, no.

Comment: question 3 can never be answered with `yes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Is it possible for an FPGA and a PC to communicate without a processor?**

*Let's make sure the term 'processor' is agreed here. An FPGA can implement a soft CPU (processor) if it has the internal gates and memory available to implement it. So processor might refer to an internal soft CPU. Or processor could mean a separate on-board IC, like a microcontroller (MCU) or microprocessor (MPU).*

Yes and many designs do. As ever, it depends on what the circuit application is trying to do. For example, FPGA firmware that outputs a sequences of ASCII characters, like a count of some event it is observing/logging can be done with simple logic.

Firmware that takes incoming data and processes it or makes decisions on it would need decision-making logic circuitry. Depending on the processing complexity, that may be most efficiently (for gates and memory) implemented by simple logic, by a Finite State Machine (FSM), by a soft CPU within the FPGA or by an external processor (MCU or MPU).

Those options are in increasing order of capability and complexity and (generally) decreasing max. speed. The designer has to trade off what processing they need to do and how many gates their budgets can afford.

**2. For communication, like sending data from a PC to an FPGA, do we need only USB or a processor too?**

As (1) describes, you can just use USB and the FPGA or use USB plus an internal soft CPU or external MCU/MPU. It all depends on what you are trying to do and what the design budgets allow.

**3. Do all FPGA dev boards have processors?**

If you mean processors external to the FPGA, like an MCU to process USB data communications then: no. Very often they use USB bridge ICs, that have a USB port on one side and a UART or programmable I/O pins on the other side. The IC's prog' I/O pins are often capable of JTAG programming of the FPGA or serial programming of a configuration Flash EPROM.

Comment: The term processor meant microprocessor. However, I got the answers. Highly appreciated. Thank you very much.